# Cannot find the environmental parameter

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I have the following one line script:

```
sudo env WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="passwd" \
    WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER="wordpress" \
    WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD="wordpress" \
    WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USER="admin" \
    WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin" \
    WORDPRESS_URL="http://0.0.0.0:8080" \
    docker run \
        --volume "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/docker/piwik-with-wordpress/scripts/../data/wordpress/db":/var/lib/mysql \
        --volume /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/docker/piwik-with-wordpress/scripts/../restore/wordpress/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD \
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE="wordpress" \
        -e MYSQL_USER=$WORDPRESS_MYSQL_USER \
        -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=$WORDPRESS_MYSQL_PASSWORD \
    mariadb
```

But for some reason I get the error:

> error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
>     You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

That means that for some reason cannot find the `$WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` environmental parameter. Why is this?

Comment: Is `WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` supposed to replace one of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` or `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` ? Have you tried to set one of those variables instead of `WORDPRESS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: No Because I run it like this in order to restore a volume for https://github.com/ellakcy/piwik-with-wordpress and uses the same parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work because setting a variable with

```
env FOO=BAR cmd
```

doesn't make the variable `FOO` available to the shell to expand it in

```
-e MYSQL_USER=$FOO
```

In other words, it it fails for the same reason as

```
FOO=BAR echo $FOO
```

doesn't output `BAR`. The shell expands `$FOO` **before** it invokes `echo`. You get the idea? Instead you should use something along

```
FOO=BAR; echo $FOO
```

Comment: Then why this script work: https://gist.github.com/pc-magas/978aeeb512be10647c8af67c6ba0c7f7 I use the same philosophy with the script above.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Because that script does not contain any `$FOO` for the shell to expand before the command is executed. It sets all environment variables with `env`. So you DO NOT use the "same philosophy" there.